# how to convert excel date (42796) to php (3/2/2017)

Tags: php

I want to display date from excel file.
If i will simply get the date from excel its showing 42796
and if use below method

```
 date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', trim($delivery_date))))
```

it is show 1970-01-01.
 And my original excel date is 3/2/2017.
Help me and thank in advance

Comment: did you go over the manual on strtotime? http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php and date http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

`$PHP_DATE = ($EXCEL_DATE - 25569) * 86400;`

You'll recognise 86400 as the number of seconds in a day and 25569 corresponds to January 1, 1970, from which UNIX dates are measured.

(Note this breaks before March 1, 1900 due to Excel thinking that 1900 was a leap year.)

Comment: thanks working good but it show me 2017-03-21 and i want 2017-3-2

Comment: the excel 3/2/2017 date and your date is 2017-03-21

Comment: $inv_date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', trim(($delivery_date - 25569) * 86400))));